# Uniform distribution in a logarithmic/isolethargic binning

Tags: distributions, logarithm, binning

Assume a variable $x$ follows a uniform distribution i.e. $P(x)-=const$.
In my case this is constant background as shown in the following figure with the green curve

[image]

This is a distribution with a linear binning and I want to subtract the green from the dark red which also follows a constant-like distribution apart from the peaks/dips seen. The same distribution plotted with a logarithmic/iselethargic binning i.e. $log(x_i) - log(x_{i-1}) = const$ looks like this (disregard the different normalization[image])

In that case I cannot subtract something constant or in other words a constant background would not look like a horizontal line. How can I translate a constant background in a linear binning to a constant background in a logarithmic one?

Comment: Are you not supposed to normalize the counts by dividing them by the lethargy widths of each bin?

Comment: @manu190466: Am I? Never thought about it. So I guess not necessarily in my case. I define a binning, then a histogram,  I sample my variable and then I fill that histogram.

Comment: Yes but narrow bins have small counts and wide bins have large counts. You need to normalize if you want handle your binned data.

Comment: @manu190466 This is a very interesting thought. And in fact if I do normalize y the bin width I get something flat. https://imgur.com/oX2Zyf1 So is this a "rule"? Forgive my ignorance

Comment: Yes, the smaller the bin is, the smaller is the probability to have a count in it.

Comment: @manu190466 That makes perfect sense! I had it all wrong for a long time although I had in mind "the biasing" that was going on when I was filling the histogram